# Do Loop variable can't be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

I have this code in which I loop until the user enters a -1. However, I get the error :

> key cannot be resolved to a variable

I have used this code before and I didn't have a problem with it, so I'm not sure why I'm having this problem.

```
System.out.println("\nEnter a number, -1 to stop : ");
do {
  int key = scan.nextInt();
  int result = interpolationSearch(integerArray, key);
  if (result != -1) {
    System.out.println("\n"+ key +" element found at position "+ result);
  }
    break;
} while (key != -1);    // quit 
System.out.println("stop");
}
```

Comment: you should initialize key before do{

Comment: move int key; to outside of do while loop

Comment: I've tried that but it stops the loop so the user can't enter another number anymore. I want it to stop only when the user enters -1.

Comment: and remove the break; this will exit your loop, you like to exit when while(false)

Answer (score 5):

You need to declare `key` outside the do loop and can get the `nextInt` every time the loop runs through. Also there is no need of `break` statement in the loop.

```
System.out.println("\nEnter a number, -1 to stop : ");
int key;
do {
  key = scan.nextInt();
  int result = interpolationSearch(integerArray, key);
  if (result != -1) {
    System.out.println("\n"+ key +" element found at position "+ result);
  }      
} while (key != -1);    // quit 
System.out.println("stop");
}
```

Comment: @JamesGrant Thats great. If it works, then you can accept any of the given answers as accepted solution and close this question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare int key outside of your do loop.  Because it is declared inside the loop, the while condition doesn't know about it.  This is called being out of scope.  Here are some examples and an explaination of scope http://java.about.com/od/s/g/Scope.htm .

Change it to this:

```
System.out.println("\nEnter a number, -1 to stop : ");
int key;
do {
  key = scan.nextInt();
  int result = interpolationSearch(integerArray, key);
  if (result != -1) {
    System.out.println("\n"+ key +" element found at position "+ result);
  }
    break;
} while (key != -1);    // quit 
System.out.println("stop");
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the response. 
However, I've tried this way but it stops the loop so the user can't enter another number anymore. I want it to stop only when the user enters -1.

Comment: I just moved the key declaration.  Your break statement will always hit.  This will break out of the loop.

Comment: He does not like this check question